# Python Try Except Direct Error To Different File

Tags: python, shell

```
numbers = [1,2,3, '4', '5', 6, 7]
for number in numbers:
    print number.real
```

I want to get the real part of the integer number as many as I could and forget those string type numbers.

(***Sorry that I was trying to use multiply by 2 but turned out "2" * integer is a legit operation***)

Here is an example

```
>>'123' * 5 
123123123123123
```

I want to have two files separately, one storing the result one storing the error. How to combine the linux shell std Input/Output/Error feature to implement what I want. 
I assume the final shell command should look like this:

```
python script.py >success.file 2>fail.file
```

Those two files should look like:

```
$cat success.file
2
4
6
12
14
$cat fail.file
8
10
```

I don't know how to implement that in python, try except?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't just catch an exception for the strings because the multiplication operator will still work on them - it'll just do the wrong thing in this case (it'll duplicate the string, so `'4'` becomes `'44'`). So, you'll need to check the type explicitly.

Assuming all numbers are integers (no floats) you can do:

```
import sys
numbers = [1,2,3, '4', '5', 6, 7]
for number in numbers:
    if isinstance(number, int):
        print number * 2
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, number
```

If you want to cope with floats as well, you can always check for that type explicitly, but this sort of approach is always a little fragile - what happens if someone uses something from the `decimal` module or even their own number-like class?

Given that the non-numeric interpretation for strings is likely the exception rather than the rule, it might be more robust to simply treat those as special cases and catch exceptions for other non-numeric types:

```
import sys
numbers = [1,2,3, '4', '5', 6, 7]
for number in numbers:
    if not isinstance(number, str) and not isinstance(number, unicode):
        try:
            print number * 2
        except Exception, e:
            print >>sys.stderr, repr(number)
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, number
```

That's for Python 2 - the string types have changed in Python 3.

Comment: Thank you so much for the correction. I didn't notice python has so much "Error tolerance". I was just trying to get an error example and failed miserable. Haha, your answer is exactly what I want! Thanks

Comment: In case someone wants to do this for Python 3.x, printing to stderr looks like this: `print(number, file=sys.stderr)`

Comment: Also, to catch all string types in one call, you could use `isinstance(number, basestring)`, of which both `str` and `unicode` are subclasses.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. Well, it's not so much error tolerance as that the `*` operator is overloaded for strings, just like `+` is to mean concatenation. If this answers your question, could you please accept it so others don't waste effort writing up new answers? @SethMMorton Yes, excellent suggestions both - I couldn't remember when `basestring` was introduced, looks like it was 2.3 so most people can probably use it without compatibility worries these days.

Answer (score 0):

First off you want something more like:

```
numbers = [1,2,3, '4', '5', 6, 7]
for number in numbers:
    print int(number) * 2
```

Secondly, could you state you problem *clearly* I have no idea what files your dealing with *etc*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sys.argv to parse commands that come after the file name. When you run

```
python myscript.py command1 command2
```

these are stored inside sys.argv, like so:

```
[in:] import sys
[in:] sys.argv
[out:]  ["myscript.py", "command1", "command2"]
```

Now that's a straightforward soution, but there's also a library called argparse if you want complicated implemantation. From there, it's really easy:

```
success = sys.argv[1]
fail = sys.argv[2]

# open the files...

for i in numbers:
     # if it's not a number, put it in the fail file
     # if it is duplicate it and put it in success file
```

I intentionally refrained from writing the entire solution. I think you can put it together yourself from there.